# How can I add an event to the Google Calendar API in Android Studio?

Tags: android, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I'm developing an app in my spare time and one of the elements requires a user to be able to create an event within the app but I want the event to be created and synced with the google calendar.

I have followed the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) but that only shows a list of current events. I essentially want to add to this but allow a user to create an event as well as view their existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the [Google Sample for Calendar API in Android](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/calendar-android-sample), this explains the basic functions like adding a calendar, editing, update and delete calendar. Also I've found more detailed tutorials [How to integrate google calendar api in android application](http://www.kpblogs.com/mobile-development/how-to-integrate-google-calendar-api-in-android-application/) and [Android Tutorial–Programming with Calendar](http://www.roman10.net/2011/08/23/android-tutorialprogramming-with-calendar/) that will help you with code implementation of adding events using your app.

Add event code:

```
void insertEvent(String summary, String location, String des, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, EventAttendee[] eventAttendees) throws IOException {
    Event event = new Event()
            .setSummary(summary)
            .setLocation(location)
            .setDescription(des);     EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(startDate)
            .setTimeZone(“America/Los_Angeles”);
    event.setStart(start);     EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(endDate)
            .setTimeZone(“America/Los_Angeles”);
    event.setEnd(end);     String[] recurrence = new String[] {“RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1”};
    event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));     event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(eventAttendees));     EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
            new EventReminder().setMethod(“email”).setMinutes(24 * 60),
            new EventReminder().setMethod(“popup”).setMinutes(10),
    };
    Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
            .setUseDefault(false)
            .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
    event.setReminders(reminders);     String calendarId = “primary”;
    //event.send
if(mService!=null)
      mService.events().insert(calendarId, event).setSendNotifications(true).execute();
}
```

Comment: Could I then just invoke this method with a button onClick?

Comment: why not ? @smithcommajohn